# count event seats sold and update seats available in different table

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have an events table, and a bookings table, once a booking is made I need to update the "available" field in the events table for that particular event

My Table structure

Events Table:

table name  = bookable_events

field names = event_name | capacity | available |id

1. Name of the event
2. Total Capacity for the event
3. Places Available
4. Numerical id of the event

Bookings Table:

table_name = bookings

field names = event_name | (event) id | persons | id

1. Event name
2. id of the event (from bookable_events table)
3. Total amount of people for the booking (max of 4)
4. Numerical id of the booking

I need to be able to sum the number of persons per event per booking

So for example

```
tribute weekend | 10 | 4 |21
soul week       | 8  | 2 |20
tribute weekend | 10 | 3 |19
soul week       | 8  | 1 |20
```

should give me a totals...
7 places sold for tribute weekend in total
3 places sold for soul week

I then need to update the events table (bookable_events) file "available" with capacity - sold seats per event thereofre showing me the available amount of seats left.

```
event_name      | capacity | available |id
tribute weekend | 50       |    43     |21
soul week       | 150      |    147    |21
```

I am using php & mysql

Any help greatly appreciated as I have no idea where to start with calculations.

Comment: `SELECT id, SUM(persons) as total_persons FROM bookings GROUP BY id`

Comment: Can't you just do `capacity` minus `booked` to determine `available`?

Comment: Thank you for your time and for reformatting my question it looks a lot neater. I now have my totals per event, thank you.

I now just need to update the available field in the event table?

Thank you

Comment: Well where are you stuck with it exactly? Have you attempted anything? For example one approach is that you could get the rows of data from the SUM query into php, loop through them and do an Update query for each ID to update the other table

Comment: So far I now have a sum of bookings for each event, thank you for that. I now need to populate the "available" field in the event table with a number per event. so at some point I need to take 'booked' away from 'capacity' per event to get my available total.

I may not be doing this the right way of course, I have already just learend to call my id's more meaningful names like events_id duh! can't have to id fields in a table. But it's all helping me learn

Comment: I forgot to mention, places are not calculated, until the booking is marked as paid in my admin system. Once they are marked as paid, the available seats should be deducted from the capacity. So after marking a booking as paid, it updates the booking table, then updates the events table with the new totals? I assume that would be the way to do it

Comment: Yes that would make sense. Are you stuck on any particular aspect of the task, which we could help with? You've done a good job of explaining the requirements, but not so much at explaining what problem you're having when implementing it. Keep in mind that Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service - you're expected to try to implement what you need, and then ask a question about a specific programming issue if you encounter one during your work.

Comment: Yes I am stuck on updating the events table

SELECT bevent_id, SUM(people) as total_persons FROM bookings GROUP BY bevent_id;

UPDATE `bookable_events` SET `sold`='total_persons' GROUP BY bevent_id;

but that isn't working

Comment: `UPDATE bookable_events SET sold='total_persons'` makes no sense. `'total_persons'` is a string. You're trying to set a number. I _think_ you were trying to read the total_persons field from the previous query, but SQL doesn't work like that. If you want a pure SQL solution it would need to be done all in one combined `UPDATE...FROM` query. Or you can take the approach I suggested previously, using PHP

Comment: OK thank you for your time

Comment: No problem. Good luck. Hopefully you're closer to your goal now - you have a couple of approaches to try out. If you try one and encounter a specific problem within it, you can ask a new question about that